# angular2 http post returns ErrorObservable

Tags: angular, ionic2, observable, reactivex

When I use `map(res => res.text())` I get this error :

> No best common type exists among return expressions.

It works when i use `map(res => res.json())`.

This is my function :

```
public register(credentials) {
  if (credentials) {
    return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
  } else {
    var creds = '.....';
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.post('url', creds, { headers: headers})
       .map(res => res.text());
  }
}
```

Comment: is the response which you are getting back is of the JSON format???

Comment: No, just an http status.

Comment: you can't return observable from undefined.